Spring boot service not registering on consul docker
I have a Spring Boot service integrated with Consul, and both are deployed on Docker instances. Although my service can successfully connect to Consul and fetch key-value configurations, it does not appear in the "Services" tab of Consul. I need assistance in troubleshooting why the service is not being registered properly with Consul.
These are my bootstrap.properties config
spring.application.name=<service-name>
spring.cloud.consul.host=<consul-host>
spring.cloud.consul.port=<consul-port>
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.config.prefix=<service-name>
spring.cloud.consul.config.default-context=application
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.register=true
spring.cloud.consul.scheme=https
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-path=/actuator/health
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.register-health-check=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.prefer-ip-address=true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.health-check-interval=10s
spring.cloud.consul.config.fail-fast=true

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

My pom.xml have required dependencies
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

When the service starts up, I’m checking the logs and noticing that the RegisteredConsul log entry is missing. Additionally, there are no logs in Consul indicating that the registration API was called. Despite this, I can connect to Consul deployed on the dev environment using the same code from my local setup, and the service is correctly displayed in the Consul "Services" tab. I need help identifying why the service isn't registering properly in the dev environment.
PS: From service's docker container If I manually execute api consul's register api, that is working fine, then service register over consul.
